# What is causing this "store to address with insufficient space" error?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

```
    struct ListNode {
        int val;
        struct ListNode *next;
    };


   struct ListNode* test = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*));

   test->val = 6;

   struct ListNode* lex = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*));

   test->next = lex;

   return test;
```

At the point I should receive a populated struct. Instead I get this:

```
   Line 14: Char 18: runtime                                                    
   error: store to address   
   0x602000000118 with      
   insufficient space for an 
   object of type 'struct ListNode 
   *' (solution.c)


   0x602000000118: note: pointer   
   points here

   be be be be  00 00 00 00 00 00 
   00 00  02 00 00 00 ff ff ff 02  
   08 00 00 20 01 00 80 70  be be 
   be be
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are only allocating space for a ListNode pointer not an actual ListNode.

try: `struct ListNode* test = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));`

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at this line of code:

```
struct ListNode* test = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode*));
```

The pointer `test` wants to point at a block of memory big enough to hold an actual, honest-to-goodness `struct ListNode` object. That object has an integer and a pointer in it.

However, your call to `malloc` says "please give me enough space to store a *pointer* to a `struct ListNode` object." That's not enough memory to hold the `struct ListNode`, hence the error.

One way to fix this would be to remove the star from the `struct ListNode` in your `sizeof` call:

```
struct ListNode* test = malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
```

Another option, which is fairly cute, is to use this approach:

```
struct ListNode* test = malloc(sizeof *test);
```

This says "the amount of space I need is the amount of space that an object pointed at by `test` would require." That happens to be `sizeof (struct ListNode)`, and there's no need to type out the type with this second approach.

As a note, the error you're getting is a *runtime* error rather than a *compiler* error. The code you have is legal C code, but just won't work when you run the program.

Comment: The code causes undefined behaviour, with no diagnostic required . So "legal" is probably not the right term  (this category also includes calling a function that you declare but don't define)